# 3D visualization with F#

Tags: 3d, f#, visualization

I would like to display a few 3D meshes and text annotations using F# and be able to pan, tilt and zoom. It has to work on Windows. Linux compatibility and open source is preferred. High level approach is better than raw OpenGL calls. What are my options?

Comment: [ILNumerics](http://ilnumerics.net/) comes to mind. Haven't used it though.

Comment: @s952163 ILNumerics looks good, but it's quite expensive. I added open source preference to my question.

Comment: It feels most of the visualization has moved to 3D.js and similar. But how about [plotly](http://muehlhaus.github.io/FSharp.Plotly/3d-surface-plots.html). It has F# bindings. Advantage would be that it should work on any platform.

Comment: Slack says try [UrhoSharp](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/urho/introduction/) :0)

Comment: Xplot / Plotly has some 3d support, is OSS and xplat - don't know if it handles what you want though, take a look here: https://tahahachana.github.io/XPlot/chart/plotly-3d-surface-plots.html

Comment: @s952163 UrhoSharp looks interesting, plotly maybe useful for simpler cases. Thanks.

Comment: If you get some experience with either would be nice to answer your own question for further reference!

Comment: I'd have a look at three.js (https://threejs.org) - with the right F#/Fable bindings, this might actually be easier to use than OpenGL and similar things...